# JavaScriptでcloud firestoreライブラリが返す値QuerySnapshotについて

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-api

Cloud Firestoreのライブラリでの戻り値についてお聞きしたいです。下記のコードを実行した時戻ってくる値についてなのですが、これはインスタンスでしょうか？　
例えばこれで `'testCollection'`　の文字列を取り出したい場合はどのように指定したら良いのでしょうか？

実行したコード

```
const docsRefs = await db.collection(dbColPath).get()
console.log(docsRefs)
```

返ってきた値

```
QuerySnapshot {
  _query: CollectionReference {
    色々ある
    },
    _queryOptions: QueryOptions {
      parentPath: [ResourcePath],
      collectionId: 'testCollection',
      色々ある
    },
    _serializer: Serializer {
      色々ある
    },
    _allowUndefined: false
  },
  色々ある
}
```

#### 追記

これってpythonで言う　`repr()` みたいなもので上記のオブジェクトに対して何か操作出来るという事ではないのでしょうか？

なんかインスタンスだったら下記のようにアクセス出来そうな気もするのですが、、、

```
class Car {
  constructor(make, model) {
    this.make = make
    this.model = model
    this.userGears = ['P', 'N', 'R', 'D']
    this.userGear = this.userGears[0]
  }
  shift(gear) {
    if(this.userGears.indexOf(gear) < 0)
      throw new Error(`ギヤ指定が正しくない: ${gear}`)
    this.userGear = gear
  }
}

const car1 = new Car("Tesla", "Model S")
console.log(car1)
console.log(car1.make)

// 実行結果

Car {
  make: 'Tesla',
  model: 'Model S',
  userGears: [ 'P', 'N', 'R', 'D' ],
  userGear: 'P'
}
Tesla
```

Answer (score 0):

データの内容は、
docsRefs.data()
関数を実行すると、取得できます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
返ってきたオブジェクトから取り出したい値とかにアクセス出来たらデバックとかやりやすいのかと思って質問しました。